# Validar un dominio con punto al final en PHP

Tags: php, url, dominio

Estoy tratando de realizar una verificación para saber si un dominio contiene un punto al final con PHP

Ejemplo:

VALIDOS (Y):

https://www.example.com/ Y

http://www.example.com/ Y

[www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/) Y

example.com/ Y

https://example.com/ Y

http://example.com Y

https://www.example.com Y

http://www.example.com Y

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) Y

example.com Y

https://example.com Y

http://example.com Y

NO VALIDOS (N):

https://www.example.com./ N

http://www.example.com./ N

www.example.com./ N

example.com./ N

https://example.com./ N

http://example.com. N

https://www.example.com. N

http://www.example.com. N

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com). N

example.com. N

https://example.com. N

http://example.com. N

Para que al final en PHP tengamos una función asi:

```
function isValidDomian($domian string):bool
{

}
```

Comment: Podés hacerle un replace al punto que este al final eliminándolo . Sino con substr() , buscas el ultimo carácter y podés verificar si es o no.

Comment: Actualice la respuesta y coloque dos opciones. Una para validar y otra para limpiar. Espero que sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad la solucion es muy facil despues de un poco de investigacion

```
 if (strrev($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])[0] != ".") {
      //Correr el programa si no tiene un punto en el dominio
    } else {
      //  throw \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException::forPageNotFound();
//aqui mostrar un error
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Limpiar o verificar últimos caracteres de un dominio

Entiendo que estas necesitando validar si al final del dominio tiene punto o barra.
Te ofrezco dos maneras de poder modificarlo para continuar con el dominio ya modificado correctamente.

#### Opción 1: Limpiando el dominio:

Existen muchas formas de realizar algo similar. En este caso la función **optimizarFinalDominio()** permite tomar el dominio de tipo string, eliminar de su parte final en caso de encontrar **punto** "." como así también **barra** la "/" devolviendo un dominio modificado.

En este caso el dominio tendrá varios puntos y barras.

```
$dominio = "https://hola.com././/.//";

function optimizarFinalDominio($unDominio){
    while (substr($unDominio, -1) == "." or substr($unDominio, -1) == "/"){
        $unDominio = substr($unDominio, 0, strlen($dominio)-1);
    }
    return "$unDominio";
}
```

El **while** nos permite verificar de manera ininterrumpida si se encuentra presente algún punto o barra en el dominio ingresado por parámetro.

Para devolvernos el ultimo carácter del dominio utilizaremos: **substr($unDominio, -1);**

Si tenemos "hola.com/" nos devolvería solo "/" que será utilizada para la condición en el while.

Para el punto y la barra del dominio necesitaremos quitarle el ultimo carácter y utilizaremos: **substr($unDominio, 0, strlen($dominio)-1);**

Si tenemos "hola.com/" nos devolvería solo "hola.com" sin "/"

Cuando ya no existan puntos o barras, el while finalizara su ciclo y se retornara un dominio modificado ( **return "$unDominio";** ).

Para comprobar la función **optimizarFinalDominio($dominio)** se puede hacer un **echo** e imprimir su resultado:

```
echo optimizarFinalDominio($dominio);
```

El resultado es el dominio sin punto y barra final:

```
https://hola.com
```

#### Opción 2: Verificando el dominio:

Si tu idea solamente es verificar el dominio:

```
function esDominioValido($unDominio){
    return !(substr($unDominio, -1) === "." or substr($unDominio, -1) === "/");
}
```

La función **esDominioValido** recibe por parámetro el dominio y solamente devuelve **true** o **false** según si cumple o no la condición.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.